# Displaying a Blank page while using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-cloud

I am new to jquery and javascript coding, and I am using the following code to read data from a csv file and use that to form a wordCloud using jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQCloud Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqcloud.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqcloud-1.0.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="csvjson.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax("http://localhost:8000/wordCloud.csv", {
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('Obtained csv file');
                var jsonobject = csvjson.csv2json(data);
                $(function() {
                  console.log('creating cloud');
                    $("#example").jQCloud(jsonobject);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
              console.log('Not Obtained');
            }
        });
      });


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example" style="width: 550px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting a blank page when i am running it. It is not even displaying any console statements.It's not executing the function at all. What might i be doing wrong. Or is there any other way to generate a word cloud obtaining the 'word'and'frequency' data from a csv file.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I would place your script tag inside the body tag, after the div.

Comment: @Keith Placement of the script on the page is irrelevant since the `$(document).ready` is used.

Comment: Nothing shown would indicate why you don't see anything in console unless there are errors thrown. For starters is page being opened on `http://localhost:8000` and not from file protocol? Are all the associated files being loaded (look in browser dev tools network)?

Comment: `csvjson` Looks like a pure NPM common.js module, as such to use in browser you would need to build it, with say webpack etc.

Comment: how does your `cvs` look like ?

Comment: are all of ur js files loading? can you check if you are missing the js files from loading...